# I am using the Matplotlib module in a graphing project. I am wondering, how would I use the animation function in a class along with subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am using multiprocessing to share data from one script to another and when I try and set the data up in a dictionary of lists there seems to be no update to my actual graph. The idea is that I am trying to show live graphs from data being received. I have ran the debugger and checked if the data is in the dictionary and it is. I followed an example of how to use the animation function from another question and everything seems to work as of setting it up but when I set the data for the graph nothing seems to get updated.

I have read about the animation from Matplotlib's documentation and this is the link I used: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Here are the parts of the class that I am using:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ['gyro', 'accel', 'mag', 'orient']
        self.axis_label = ['_x', '_y', '_z', '_w']
        self.labels = ["Gyro", "Accelerometer", "Magnetometer", "Orientation"]
        self.colors = ['b', 'g', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'r']
        self.data = {}
        self.header = []
        self.running = True

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
        plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.15, hspace=0.43, top=0.96, right=0.98, bottom=0.02, left=0.05)

        self.ax = []
        for i in range(4):
            self.ax.append(self.fig.add_subplot(4, 1, i + 1))

        self.lines = [[], [], [], []]
        for i in range(len(self.ax)):
            ln1, = self.ax[i].plot([], [], label=self.types[i] + "_x", color=self.colors[0])
            self.lines[i].append(ln1)
            ln2, = self.ax[i].plot([], [], label=self.types[i] + "_y", color=self.colors[1])
            self.lines[i].append(ln2)
            ln3, = self.ax[i].plot([], [], label=self.types[i] + "_z", color=self.colors[-1])
            self.lines[i].append(ln3)
            if i == 3:
                ln4, = self.ax[i].plot([], [], label=self.types[i] + "_w", color=self.colors[2])
                self.lines[i].append(ln4)

    def receive_data(self, q1, q2):
        received_header = False
        while self.running:
            msg = q1.get()
            self.running = q2.get()
            if not received_header:
                self.header = msg
                for val in self.header:
                    self.data[val] = []
                received_header = True
            else:
                for i in range(len(msg)):
                    for j in range(len(msg[i])):
                        self.data.get(self.header[j]).append(msg[i][j])

    def animate_init(self):
        for ax in self.ax:
            ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
            ax.set_xlim(0, 500)
            ax.grid()
            ax.legend()

        return self.lines

    def animate(self, frames):
        for lines in self.lines:
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                lines[i].set_data(self.data['timestamp'], self.data[self.types[i] + self.axis_label[i]])
        return self.lines
```

In my main:

```
def initiate_graph(q1, q2):
    g = Graph()
    gThread = threading.Thread(target=g.receive_data, args=(q1, q2,))
    gThread.start()
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(g.fig, g.animate, init_func=g.animate_init, interval=100)
    plt.show()
```